# Firestore Datastore Mode write/read consistency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a project created with Cloud Firestore Datastore Mode.

I perform write operation using `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore.put` **without** transaction, just after performing write I perform read operation for the just written record using `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore.get`. But as far as I see in some cases read operation doesn't return just written value.

This looks like eventual consistency but according to this https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore 'Cloud Firestore Datastore Mode' is strongly consistent database.

Is it possible that write operation **isn't strong consistent** if you perform it **without** transaction? According to this https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions transactions are optional and I didn't find any information that they are required to make Firestore Datastore strongly consistent.

Is it required to setup something to make strong consistency work?

Comment: Are you checking for any error returned during the put? Are you ensuring the key returned from put is what is always used for get?

Comment: Yes, I am checking for errors and doesn't receive any. Yes, I am sure that I am using the correct key.

Comment: Are you waiting for the write operation to finish? It should be strongly consistent. Please provide code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you aren’t using transactions, there is a chance that your read action will execute before your write action finishes. This could happen because of a large volume of traffic or a large write size. Using transactions will prevent this from happening because you can allow a read action to only run after a write action finishes.

Comment: Does this mean that Firestore Datastore Mode doesn't strong consistent without transaction for write+read operations? Because as far as I understand strong consistency if you perform `read` after `write` they should be executed consistently and `read` should get the updated value.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly how big your writes are or how you have your querying logiced. These could be affecting your consistency. But to answer your question, yes Firestore Datastore Mode is strongly consistent without transactions. But to ensure that you will read what you just wrote in consecutive operations, use transactions for each operation.

Comment: @MaximusMacdonald your answer doesn't make much sense to me.  If the size of the write affects read consistency, then it simply isn't strongly consistent.

Comment: @user239558 If you are using Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode, then you have strong consistency on all your queries. Strongly consistent queries only guarantee write consistency, not read consistency. In other words, you can write as much as you want and that data will always change. But without using a transaction, you may not be able to see your most recent changes even if you have strong consistency.

Comment: @MaximusMacdonald What do you mean exactly by "Strongly consistent queries only guarantee write consistency"? Isn't a query by definition a read operation? When you query the datastore you are reading some entities. Can you clarify?